# Converting Red Hat syntax to Ubuntu for networking

Tags: networking, server, configuration

I have the following Red language - how would I convert this into Ubuntu syntax? And what would the relevant files be?

In `/etc/sysconfig/network` I have

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=onyx.boisestate.edu
GATEWAY=132.178.208.1
```

In `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` I have

```
DEVICE=eth1
BOOTPROTO=none
BROADCAST=132.178.223.255
IPADDR=132.178.208.159
NETMASK=255.255.240.0
NETWORK=132.178.208.0
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
PEERDNS=no
GATEWAY=132.178.208.1
TYPE=Ethernet
```

In `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` I have

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
BROADCAST=192.168.0.255
IPADDR=192.168.0.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.0.0
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
PEERDNS=no
TYPE=Ethernet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hostname from `/etc/sysconfig/network` is set in `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1  onyx.boisestate.edu  onyx
```

and you could add it as:

```
132.178.208.159 onyx.boisestate.edu  onyx
```

The Ethernet interfaces from `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX` are set in `/etc/network/interfaces` file like the following:

```
auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255

auto eth1
    iface eth1 inet static
    address 132.178.223.159
    netmask 255.255.240.0
    network 132.178.208.0
    broadcast 132.178.223.255
    gateway 132.178.208.1
```

Hope this helps!